# Quickbooks webconnector Integration 1048 error

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using QuickBooks 2013 pro on server A, I have a self signed cert on server B. I had server A navigate to the services on SERVER B install the self signed cert into trusted root. Then had the web connector on SERVER A try to add an application. It is coming back with this error

> qbwc1048: QuickBooks Web Connector Could not verify the web
>   application server certificate.

Any help in solving this would be great. Thank you very much

Comment: Close all INTERNET EXPLORER windows on SERVER A. Visit SERVER B from SERVER A in INTERNET EXPLORER. Do you get an error message/notice about SSL? If you do, then you haven't imported your SSL cert correctly. Also, post your Web Connector logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@consolibyte Closed all IE windows and re-imported the SSL works now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having a similar problem, it may not be the certificate at all. It could be the server is closing the connection or returning an error code.

For more details, first click `file -> clear log` in the web connector. Then, try adding your application again. After it fails, click the `view log` button at the top right. Scroll down for more details on what happened.

You will see something like, `remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized`, or a similar message that is far more useful than what appears in the dialogue box.